# Ubuntu 15.04 crashes with scattered screen

Tags: 15.04, java, screen, ram, crash

I have recently installed 4GB DDR3 RAM (Innex) with an existing 2GB RAM (Dynet), currenlty it runs with 6GB RAM.

I use Eclipse, Java, Chrome extensively for my development purpose

But after this additional RAM Ubuntu crashes often and needs reboot, it happens every one hour or before/after an hour.

I installed `htop` and see the increase in RAM but still it had 2GB RAM remaining, I added swap 4GB but still no luck.

Could someone please help me what's wrong with my machine.

```
$ java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5.8G       4.0G       1.7G       512M        82M       2.3G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.7G       4.1G
Swap:         4.0G         0B       4.0G

$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           590M  8.5M  582M   2% /run
/dev/sda6        36G   14G   20G  42% /
tmpfs           2.9G  211M  2.7G   8% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           590M   56K  590M   1% /run/user/1000
```

and Latest version of `Eclipse (Mars)`

[image]

**Please note:**

Its dual boot machine, Windows works fine without any issues, problem only with Ubuntu.

Windows 8.1 has 12GB of page file does it make any difference, Ubuntu had no swap space I added 4GB after this issue

**Looks like it's a problem with Ubuntu 15.04 OS, planning to downgrade to 14.04**

Comment: Power down then reseat snugly your memory cards

Comment: slot 0 has 4GB RAM and 1 has 2GB RAM

Comment: Does it work with original card without new card ? ... I've heard memory cards should be matched ... Does it work with just new card without original card ? ... If so I'd get another of your 4 gig card and go to 8 total and leave out the original 2 gig card

Comment: With 2GB both works fine, haven't tried 4GB alone but no issues in Windows 8.1 with 6GB RAM, what could be wrong with Ubuntu?

Comment: Understandably you may not be interested in forfeiting your originally installed 2GB, and go from 6GB to 4GB. But ***do try*** @ScottStensland's suggestion. Try working with everything else as is only with your new 4GB RAM module(s). If after a day you do not detect an itch with Ubuntu, you'll have your answer.

Comment: Will try and update ASAP

Comment: me too...experience this type of scrambled screen ..in Ubuntu 14.04 with  kernel 3.19

Comment: Have swapped the slots of RAM, Same issue occurred.

Comment: Removed 2GB RAM also, runs with 4GB RAM, same issue occurred  but no issues in Windows 8.1

Comment: Looks like it's a problem with Ubuntu 15.04 OS